# JavaFX button event triggers only once

Tags: events, button, javafx

So i have this JavaFX application, which contains a button, that is supposed to open the DirectoryChooser onclick. When i trigger it once, it does what it was supposed to do, perfectly fine. As soon as i close the DirectoryChooser Dialog, the button doesn't do anything anymore. I was searching the web for some "event resetting" or something similar, because i thought maybe the Event was still "active" and therefore doesn't trigger anymore, but without any results:

```
// first attempt
button.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, 
    new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
            // dirChooser.setTitle("Select Directory:");
            file = dirChooser.showDialog(primaryStage);

            // just incase only the DirectoryChooser wasn't opening
            System.out.println("asdf");

            // updates the application view with the new selected path
            update();

            // not sure, if this affects anything
            // found it while looking for resetting of events
            e.consume();
        };
    }
);
// secont attempt
button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
        DirectoryChooser dirChooser = new DirectoryChooser();
        dirChooser.setTitle("Select Directory:");
        file = dirChooser.showDialog(primaryStage);
        update();
    }
});
```

Not sure if this is just a complete wrong approach, or if i'm missing something important there. I hope you guys can figure it out.

Comment: What do you mean by "the button doesn't do anything anymore"? The event handler is not being triggered for second and later clicks?

Comment: Well, the DiaglogChooser doesn't open, there is no console output, it seems the handle function isn't called. So yes, it's not triggered.

Comment: for debugging purpose, can you comment out the dirChooser (and update()) line in code and try again to click. Is there console output?

Comment: Only System.out now, and it does write "asdf" everytime i press the button...alright, i found the problem, will post answer

Comment: Your JavaFX and OS versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after the help of Uluk Biy, i got the problem. In the update routine, the button is newly created and therefore it's event handler is not existent anymore. I added the button to the attributes so I don't need to replace it everytime when calling the update routine, and the event handler is still existent.